# Invoke native code from Javascript in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing an universal application using Cordova.

I want to add some features, for example authentication via `Touch ID` (fingerprint auth). In order to do this it's requested **not** to use a framework/library from Github/Internet so I want to do it in **native code** (Objective-C for iOS, Java for Android etc).

My problem is: since my app is a standard client application which uses HTML, Javascript (AngularJs) and CSS, how can I invoke some native code within the app life cycle? For example, if I'm inside a specific page (HTML) of my application, can I call an Objective-C method which implements the fingerprint authentication?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: dig through the anatomy of a cordova plugin... they include native code

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-touch-id